How to Implement Turn-by-Turn Navigation Using mapbox_maps_flutter Package in Flutter?
I am using the official mapbox_maps_flutter package in my Flutter app to display a map and add various functionalities. I want to implement turn-by-turn navigation within the app using this package.
Has anyone successfully implemented turn-by-turn navigation with mapbox_maps_flutter? If so, could you please provide a step-by-step guide or share the necessary code snippets and configurations to achieve this?
I tried using the flutter_mapbox_navigation package for navigation, but it is causing issues with the existing mapbox_maps_flutter integration.

The mapbox_maps_flutter package is pretty much just maps, but it is an official package from Mapbox which aims to take a flutter-native approach.
flutter_mapbox_navigation on the other hand is a community project which appears to depend on the native Android and iOS navigation SDKs from Mapbox directly (see build.gradle). It appears to use the stock UI which is designed to be standalone and presented as a full-screen experience.
Given the fundamental differences, I would not expect any compatibility between the two.
I cannot find any related projects which would help either. Building a customized navigation experience is extremely difficult. But since that's what you're asking for, here are a few ideas.

Use flutter_mapbox_navigation exclusively. This will take some effort to enable whatever customizations you may need.
Use the core components for iOS and Android (note: I'm not as sure on the Android link; the docs are far more chaotic over there). You'll have to build the UI from scratch, but you can build it completely in Flutter with the official package if that's what you need.


I have implemented it on my app but the package has a lot of missing features because is outdated and most of the options there are not working. But it works good as simple navigation.

Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thanks for posting this, but it doesn't fully answer the question, which is How to Implement Turn-by-Turn Navigation Using mapbox_maps_flutter Package in Flutter?  Is there any chance you could [edit] your answer to explain how you implemented it in your app so others can learn from what you did, as suggested by the help center?  Thanks!
